# How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(2n+1)!} {2^{3n} \; (n!)^2} = 2\sqrt{2} \;$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

I found out that the sum
   $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(2n+1)!} {2^{3n} \; (n!)^2}$$
converges to $2\sqrt{2}$.

But right now I don't have enough time to figure out how to solve this.
I would really appreciate any help. Just one tiny hint might help too.

Comment: you can try to compute the partial sum

Comment: I did try that. But I have to show the whole method on exam paper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Hint:** Observe that (by the binomial theorem for instance)
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(2n)!} {(n!)^2}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}, \quad |x|<\frac{1}{2}.
$$ Then multiply by $x$ and perform a termwise differentiation and you readily obtain the desired result with $x^2=\dfrac{1}{2^3}.$

Comment: Good Job. One quick question : how have you derived the Right Side of the Identity from the left?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Thanks. They are many ways to prove it. Here I consider that the OP already knows the MacLaurin series for $(1+u)^\alpha$ (successive derivatives of $(1+u)^\alpha$ are easy to find).

Comment: Useful hint. :)

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{\verts{\mu} < {1 \over 4}}$:

> \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}{\pars{2n + 1}! \over \pars{n!}^{2}}}
> &=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\pars{2n + 1}\mu^{n}{2n \choose n}
> =\pars{2\mu\,\totald{}{\mu} + 1}
> \color{#c00000}{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}{2n \choose n}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}{2n \choose n}}
&=\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{2n} \over z^{n + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z}
\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\bracks{\pars{1 + z}^{2}\mu \over z}^{n}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over z}{1 \over 1 - \pars{1 + z}^{2}\mu/z}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=-\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over \mu z^{2} + \pars{2\mu - 1}z + \mu}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=-\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over \mu\pars{z - r_{-}}\pars{z - r_{+}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&\mbox{where}\quad \boxed{\ds{\quad r_{\pm}
\equiv {1 - 2\mu \pm \root{1 - 4\mu} \over 2\mu}\quad}} 
\end{align}

> Note that $\ds{\verts{r_{-}}\ <\ 1}$ and $\ds{\verts{r_{+}}\ >\ 1}$ such that:

\begin{align}
\color{#c00000}{\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}{2n \choose n}}
&=-\,{1 \over \mu}\,{1 \over r_{-} - r_{+}}
=-\,{1 \over \mu}{1 \over -2\root{1 - 4\mu}/\pars{2\mu}}
={1 \over \root{1 - 4\mu}}
\end{align}

> Then,
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\mu^{n}{\pars{2n + 1}! \over \pars{n!}^{2}}}
> &=\pars{2\mu\,\totald{}{\mu} + 1}{1 \over \root{1 - 4\mu}}
> =\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over \root{1 - 4\mu}} + {4\mu \over \pars{1 - 4\mu}^{3/2}}}
> \end{align}

Set $\ds{\mu = {1 \over 8}}$ in both members:
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{n\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\pars{2n + 1}! \over 2^{3n}\pars{n!}^{2}}}
&=\color{#66f}{\large2\root{2}} \approx {\tt 2.8284}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice complementary answer! (+1)