# summation of a finite sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

What is the summation of the finite sequence:
$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{1}{i}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{2i - 2}\\
{i - 1}
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{2n + 2 - 2i}\\
{n + 1 - i}
\end{array}} \right)} $$

My professor leave us the answer: $\frac{{2n}}{{n + 1}}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{2n}\\
n
\end{array}} \right)$, if I remembered it right.

But why such a complex summation has such a neat closed form expression? I'm stupid:(

Comment: There is no stupid question ! Only answers can be. If there is something you don't understand, ask ! You are at the right place here. I am sorry to being dumb in this area (and many other) and so I cannot help you. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I can't see how you're dumb

Comment: @DigitalBrain. You cannot conceive how much I am in so many areas; there are many times here (a site I very much enjoy) where I don't understand the question and if I do, I don't understand the answer !! I am not a mathematician, remember ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I find it quite interesting. Go ahead !!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You may use the same [technique exposed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002210/what-is-the-summation-of-such-a-finite-sequence/1002235#1002235).

From
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{2i}i x^i=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}},\quad |x|<\frac14, \tag1
$$
by integration, you get
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac1i\binom{2i-2}{i-1} x^i=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4x} \right),\quad |x|<\frac14. \tag2
$$
and then use the [Cauchy product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

Comment: I've solved it following your ideas! Thank you so much!:)